# Django makemigrations not writing out migration file (but thinks it has)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm having issues trying to add migrations to a database. Running makemigrations for the first time outputs the usual text you would expect for a succesful makemigrations execution:

```
Migrations for 'foo':
  0021_auto_20160425_1023.py:
    - Create model blah
    - Add field x to z
    - Add field y to z
```

Listing the files in the makemigrations folder however, shows that this migrations file does not exist. Running the makemigrations command a second time:

```
No changes detected
```

It looks like I have full permissions on the migrations folder, no errors were output on any makemigrations command, yet nothing seems to be happening. Going into the Docker shell, Django can't migrate the database.

Update: The issue was related to an incorrectly executed setup.py installation, which set up a separate instance of my code with my site-packages. Setting it up correctly showed that the code had been working fine from the start.

Comment: Which directory are you checking? Are other migration files (before `0021`) there?

Comment: I'm checking the foo/migrations directory, which contains all migration files from 0001_initial to 0020_etc. I tried specifically running 'python manage.py makemigrations foo' but that yields the same results.

Comment: Are you running this in development or production?

Comment: In development. It's run through docker if that's any help, but that particular world is all brand new to me at the moment.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I'm running in Docker.. The migration file is not written. In INSTALLED_APPS, I have added my app: ca.apps.screening